# Clear remaining input from stdin using C without stdio

Tags: c, text, stdin

I am trying to write a C program that will take user input up to X characters in length and then truncate the rest of the input.

As it stands, if the user enters less than X characters before a line feed is seen, it will read those characters fine and print them properly. If I enter more than X characters, it will read in X characters and then either spit out the characters into my command line or (if I run a loop to check for no more characters) it will continue forever.

This is my code

```
int numChar = 0;
int charRead = 0;
char buffer;
do {
    charRead = read(0, &buffer, 1);
    
    if(charRead > 0) {
        //save output out of the function
    }
    
    numChar++;
} while(charRead > 0);
```

What I tried to do here was check if a character was read in, and if not then end the input phase, however I realise that read() from stdin will always wait for more characters to become available and I can't figure out how to get around this.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that seems to be quite eloquent. If anyone finds something that can be fixed, please point it out so I can learn. Cheers

Code is as follows

```
bool hasFoundLF = false;
int numChar = 0;
int charRead = 0;
char buffer;

while(!hasFoundLF) {
    charRead = read(0, &buffer, 1);
    
    if(buffer == '\n') {
        hasFoundLF = true;
        return numChar;
    }
    
    //Maximum number of characters to be read in
    if(numChar < STRMAXLEN-1) {
        output[numChar] = buffer;
        numChar++;
    }
}

if(!hasFoundLF) {
    return numChar;
} else {
    return -1
}
```

Comment: If your input file descriptor hits EOF before it finds a newline, your code will fall into an infinite loop.

Comment: I made the assumption that this would only be used on stdin since it is hardcoded that way, but that is a good point. How might I modify the code to check if it is at the end of a file? As I understand it, you can't check that on a character stream. Am I mistaken?

Comment: When you reach EOF, `read()` will return `0`.  The input file descriptor can be a redirected file, it can be a socket, and even if it is from a user on a keyboard that user can enter `CTRL-D` on most terminals and close the input stream to your process.

Comment: Ah this is new to me. So there isn't a way to automatically notify the program of the end of a character stream, but ctrl-d signals that to them? Coolio, thanks for that information, that's quite handy. Cheers!